# How to prevent Docker from editing my hosts file?

Tags: docker

Since a recent Docker update on my Windows machine, Docker Desktop started adding entries to my `etc\hosts` file. I'm not sure which build introduced it, but I'm currently on Docker Desktop Community 2.1.0.1 (31799).

I want my `etc\hosts` file to contain only the following entry:

`127.0.0.1       localhost host.docker.internal`

But every now and then, Docker Desktop adds additional entries resulting in:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost host.docker.internal
# Added by Docker Desktop
10.4.123.44 host.docker.internal
10.4.123.44 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

If I remove them, they eventually reappear. How do I prevent Docker from adding these entries?

Comment: Dealing with the same issue, Docker Desktop adds your network address to the hosts file, and doesn't even consider existing entries so you end up with multiple conflicting entries for host.docker.internal and gateway.docker.internal and neither resolve causing random connect issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you not want to allow Docker to manage your hosts file? I think you may get some unwanted behaviour if you do.

That said, you can probably just make the file read only.

`Right-click > Properties > Check Read Only > Apply`

You'll have to update this when making changes but it will also prevent Docker from writing to it.

Comment: The issue with Docker Desktop altering your hostfile is that a reverse-dns lookup on your LAN IP resolves to Docker Desktop’s hostname (`host.docker.internal`) instead of your machine name. Then some applications, such as Spring Boot apps, will use that name, causing more issues down the line, e.g. when your IP address changes.

Answer (score -1):

A common approach of preventing Docker from rewriting content on a host directory is anonymous volumes. This is what I use in docker-compose.yml:

```
...
volumes:
      - ./main/server/src:/server/src
      - /server/node_modules
```

`main/server/src` are folders in my host folder where my project lives.
(`Dockerfile` is inside the `server` directory).

And `/server/src` are folders inside my container ( `WORKDIR` path set in Dockerfile)

The first line allows to sync my host directory with the content of container, which enables live reload.
The second line prevents 'node_modules' packages to be copied from your host to a container.

Important to note, that all the rest files and folders inside the container will not be rewriting the host. Except for the `src`.

Comment: The question is about Docker Desktop modifying the Windows’ `hosts` file, not about docker containers modifying files outside of the container.

Answer (score -2):

```
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
```

I had to use the in Laravel .env db_host entry in order for the breeze app to authenticate with the database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).